# How can i center this Google map on user local position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla, geocoding, google-gears

I try to manage some changes at the code of Joomla Module file that show a google map to get it working center automatically on user location:

i found on the google documentation this script write in Google maps api V3 for geocode that works great standing alone and seems to be very accurate.  See it on this page: http://www.urbanclaim.com/new.php

i already have this problem: (you can see it using the link above)

### after a user click on for sharing his location, never changes in the module's map. i try to put an alert in the code ang give me a null value for the local coordinates..   someone of you can help me with a debug in firebug o give me an advice on this?

i SOLVED it..this site is really useless.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you are looking for a element with the ID of `location` but I do not see the element in the DOM nor do I see it being added by your JavaScript, once I added a element with that ID to the DOM via FireBug, your code worked for me.

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply ..really it works for you??? plese tell me how and where i can do it? Thanks!!

Comment: Add a element with a id of `location` like `<div id="location"></div>`

Comment: i have put it in my code but the only thing that appear is the text "Found location via W3C standard", and the map doesn't refresh to a local center. what's appened on your video?   ( i can share the code for a better solution, i can past it here? ) thnaks.

Comment: Try uncommenting out the `showMap` function calls also, right now they are `//showMap`, change them to `showMap`

Comment: The showMap function is loaded in via a JS file and it is now not being found. Basically you need to find the map object, e.g. when the window loads, maybe set it to a global variable. After the success callback, than call centerMap on the map object. I would recommend reading http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html

Comment: yes, i know, but i'm not able to do this..i'm really sorry, i read all the documentation on Google Code but i'm not an hard programmer, this is a no-profit project for civil protection.. if you can help me, please!  just tell me where i can share my code file

Comment: ok..i found the "ShowMap" function and i declare it with this:  function showMap(latLong, zoom){
      var options = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: latLong,
        
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"map\"), options);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLong,
          map: map,
          title:\"Your location\"
      });
    }            can you see some changes on my page? Now how can i set it to a global variable as you said?  thanks. Luca

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off in a chatroom. SO is a Q&A; it is not optimised for one-on-one step-by-step tuition.

Comment: yes Tomalak, this is what i'll do, also because Cristiangeek tell me to do some changes at my code saying "your code worked for me" and point me in a completely wrong direction. So i only lost my time with asking this question. good advice. bye.